# How do I make this thing in dock into one?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image: Screen1]

As you can see on this screenshot in the Dock there are two icons of TeamSpeak. If I want to launch it i just press the square one and then it "creates" the round one. So here is my question: Can I somehow make it into one (With this little orange line that says that it is turned on)?